# SSIS - Excel Source

Tags: excel, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl, ssis-2017

Why when I open the task Excel Source on my SSIS (vs2017) this one generates an automatic empty file with sheet names like  "a266ff2a662e84b639da".  is possible to disable this action?

[task Excel Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENJpO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DataFlowTask set Delay Validation to True

Comment: You might achieve increased appreciation of your answer if you add an explanation to the current bare bones solution proposal. How does it work? Why does it help?